# How to compare Array of JSON Objects using DataWeave and return the indexes

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I know there are lot of DataWeave functions which does the job. But trying to find something for my use.

Compare two array of JSON Objects and return the indexes.

Here is the payload1: `[ { "a": 1 }, { "a": 2 }, { "a": 3 } ]` and payload2: `[{"a":2}]`

SO i would like to see the result as index=1 of payload1. Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some functions you can use are `find` or `dw::core::Arrays::indexOf`.

This satisfies your initial requirement:

```
import indexOf from dw::core::Arrays
var payload1 = [ { "a": 1 }, { "a": 2 }, { "a": 3 } ]
var payload2 = [ {"a":2} ]
---
"index=" ++ (payload1 indexOf payload2[0]) ++ " of payload1"
```

This is a more complex scenario using `find` to get multiple indexes for multiple elements:

```
var payload1 = [ { "a": 1 }, { "a": 2 }, { "a": 3 } , { "a": 2 }]
var payload2 = [{ "a": 2 }, { "a": 3 }, { "a": 5 } ]
---
{ items: 
  payload2 reduce ((item, indexes = []) -> 
    do {
      var itemIndexes = payload1 find item
      ---
      if(isEmpty(itemIndexes))
        indexes 
      else
        indexes+ ( {
          item: item,
          indexes: (payload1 find item)
        })
    }
  )
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
{ "items": [
    {
      "item": { "a": 2 },
      "indexes": [ 1, 3 ]
    },{
      "item": { "a": 3 },
      "indexes": [ 2 ]
    }
]}
```